# Using IIF in Access give me aggregate function error

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions, iif

```
SELECT Bot.BetType, 
   Sum(Bot.Result) AS Won, 
   IIf([Bot]![Market Name] Like "*Place*", "Place", "Win") AS Type
FROM Bot
GROUP BY Bot.BetType, Type;
```

Getting error:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression `If([Bot]![Market Name] Like "*Place*", "Place", "Win")` as part of an aggregate function.

I did not find a result from google. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use aliases in GROUP BY:

```
SELECT Bot.BetType, 
   Sum(Bot.Result) AS Won, 
   IIf([Bot]![Market Name] Like "*Place*", "Place", "Win") AS Type
FROM Bot
GROUP BY Bot.BetType, IIf([Bot]![Market Name] Like "*Place*", "Place", "Win");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use  a subquery, I think you can use the alias:

```
SELECT B.BetType, 
       Sum(B.Result) AS Won,
       type
from (select b.*, IIf([Bot]![Market Name] Like "*Place*", "Place", "Win") AS Type
      FROM Bot b
     ) b
GROUP BY b.BetType, Type;
```